# Sticky Footer Not Working on Single Page

Tags: css, sticky-footer

It seems the sticky-footer that I have used works great on every page except my thank you page after submitting my web form.

I can't for the life of me figure out why on that ONE page it drops off the bottom of the screen.

Anyone see the issue?

http://kennlucas.com/contact-thanks.htm

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: because you have 100% height set on `.pageWrap` and its taking the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

```
.pageWrap {
   min-height: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   /* padding-bottom: 39px; */
}
```

This is your code, but the min-height should not be set and the footer should be positioned in another way.